# in SQL create flag according to one variable over the 6 months data

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to extract a matrix from a table 'CARAT_AGG'.
where BILLLING_ACCOUNT_ID is my primary key(CUSTOMER COUNT).
I want all DISTINCT BILLLING_ACCOUNT_ID whose CUSTOMER_STATUS is 'ACTIVE' to be flagged as 1  and CUSTOMER_STATUS as 'null' to be FLAGGED AS 0 over the month.
 and then create a final column summation of all the 6 columns with 1 or 0.

I have written the below query is someone could help.
[image: output should look like this]

```
select DISTINCT MONTH_YEAR, count(BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID), 

sum(case when month_year = '01-APR-18' then NVL(CUSTOMER_STATUS,0) else 1 end)  over (partition by MONTH_YEAR) APR_STATUS,
sum(case when month_year = '01-MAY-18' then NVL(CUSTOMER_STATUS,0) else 1 end)  over (partition by MONTH_YEAR) MAY_STATUS,
sum(case when month_year = '01-JUN-18' then NVL(CUSTOMER_STATUS,0) else 1 end)  over (partition by MONTH_YEAR) JUN_STATUS,
sum(case when month_year = '01-JUL-18' then NVL(CUSTOMER_STATUS,0) else 1 end)  over (partition by MONTH_YEAR) JUL_STATUS,
sum(case when month_year = '01-AUG-18' then NVL(CUSTOMER_STATUS,0) else 1 end)  over (partition by MONTH_YEAR) AUG_STATUS,
sum(case when month_year = '01-SEP-18' then NVL(CUSTOMER_STATUS,0) else 1 end)  over (partition by MONTH_YEAR) SEP_STATUS
from CARAT_AGG 
group by MONTH_YEAR
order by MONTH_YEAR
;
```

Comment: Please post formatted text rather than images, and include sample raw data as well as your current results and the result you're trying to achieve for that sample.

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this as:

```
select BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID, 
       sum(case when month_year = date '2018-04-01' and customer_status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as APR_STATUS,
       sum(case when month_year = date '2018-05-01' and customer_status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as MAY_STATUS,
       sum(case when month_year = date '2018-06-01' and customer_status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as JUN_STATUS,
       sum(case when month_year = date '2018-07-01' and customer_status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as JUL_STATUS,
       sum(case when month_year = date '2018-08-01' and customer_status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as AUG_STATUS,
       sum(case when month_year = date '2018-09-01' and customer_status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as SEP_STATUS,
       sum(case when month_year in (date '2018-04-01', date '2018-05-01', date '2018-06-01', date '2018-07-01', date '2018-08-01', date '2018-09-01') and customer_status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as total
from CARAT_AGG 
group by BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID
order by BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID
;
```

Notes:

- Oracle has a nice syntax for date constants -- using the `date` keyword (this is actually standard SQL).
- You want one row per `BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID` so that should be your `GROUP BY` clause.
- You want to check for active status, so do so explicitly.